# Why is x-axis in graph always alphabetical? How can I order x-axis according to my data?

Tags: stata

I have a list of countries, gdp, and 2 variables for employment

```
cntry
gdppc
ie_dummy
fe_dummy
```

Data is initially ordered alphabetically according to cntry, so i first

```
gsort -gdppc
```

Sort it by descending GDP, highest to lowest.
Now when I generate my graph

```
graph bar ie_dummy fe_dummy, over(cntry) stack
```

The x-axis which country is still alphabetically ordered, not reflecting the order of the data.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wherever this idea originates (MS Excel, maybe), the lesson here is that you don't sort the elements of the graph sorting the data set itself. `help graph bar` points to a corresponding `sort` option, used within the graphing command. A simple example is:

```
clear
set more off

sysuse educ99gdp

generate total = private + public

graph hbar (asis) public private, ///
    over(country, sort(total) descending) stack ///
    title( "Spending on tertiary education as % of GDP, 1999", span pos(11) ) ///
    subtitle(" ") ///
    note("Source:  OECD, Education at a Glance 2002", span)
```

In this example, the sorting is done based on the variable `total`, which is the sum of the `public` and `private` shares of spending on education.

Comment: That's an incredibly valuable lesson, thank you kindly Roberto.