# Sort by variable in twoway scatter. X-axis stays alphabetical and sort produces gibberish: why?

Tags: stata

I have two variables:

```
ie_ctotal
cntry2
```

Note: `cntry2` is an `encode`d version of a string variable `cntry`: I don't know if this may be affecting things.

I want a `twoway scatter` of `ie_ctotal` and `cntry2`, and I want to SORT this scatter by another variable `gdppc`,

```
 twoway  || scatter ie_ctotal cntry2, c(1) xlabel(,valuelabel)
```

The above without `sort` works fine. Once I introduce `sort`, however,

```
 twoway  || scatter ie_ctotal cntry2, c(1) sort(gdppc) xlabel(,valuelabel)
```

The graph turns gibberish, or rather it connects according to the `sort`, but the x axis remains alphabetical, making the connections seem scribbled.

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

Note: I don't want to `sort` the original data, because I was advised in previous questions that this is a bad idea. So I want to `sort` the data only for this one graph.

Comment: The advice given in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29378155/2077064) not to unnecessarily `sort` the data, applied to the case there discussed. For other graphs, you can find similar `sort` options that are "embedded" in the graphing command itself. This is the case here too, and @Nick has provided a way in his latest update (#4). However, a time will come when you have to do extensive prior manipulations in order to make your graph, and that can involve `sort`ing the data. The recommendation is to read the graph documentation, review examples, and then plan a strategy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reproducible example here, and not even a graph, but it is possible to guess the problem.

You are typing above

```
c(1)
```

which is ill-advised, although Stata does the right thing. It would be better to type

```
c(l)
```

which instructs Stata to join data points on your graph in a line. (Nod to @Dimitriy V. Masterov on this detail.)

In your first example, the values of `cntry2` define the *x* axis.

As you say, the effect of `sort(gdppc)` is to connect points in order of their values from lowest `gdppc` to highest. The result is clearly not what you want.

Here is a dopey reproducible example that makes the point.

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. scatter mpg weight, sort(price) c(l)
```

[image]

You want to sort the countries into `gdppc` order. This is like sorting `make` in Stata's auto data according to `mpg`, but then plotting `weight`. Here I do this just for foreign cars. It's not a very good graph, but it sounds close in spirit to what you want. This solution requires installation of `labmask`, for which `search labmask` and then download from the *Stata Journal* website.

```
sysuse auto, clear
keep if foreign
sort mpg 
gen obsno = _n 
labmask obsno, values(make) 
scatter weight obsno, xla(1/22, valuelabel ang(v) noticks) xtitle("")
```

[image]

In a nutshell: the `sort()` option here defines a connection order; it doesn't map the *x* axis variable to a reshuffled version. That you need to do before the graphics.

UPDATE In fact, you can get essentially the same graph without any prior manipulation:

```
graph dot (asis) weight if foreign, over(make, sort(mpg) label(ang(v)))  vertical linetype(line) lines(lc(none))
```

This is going along with the OP's interest in putting labelled categories on the *x* axis. A graph easier to read would put them on the *y* axis: then text can be read left to right. To get that, omit the `vertical` above: that is the default for `graph dot`. Although the command above omits guide lines by setting their colour to `none`, very thin light colour guide lines can help.

Comment: I am not sure c(1) is illegal.

Comment: @Dimitriy V. Masterov Good point: Stata ignores it and uses the default, which turns out to be what was intended. I'll edit. (When I used to do this by accident in Stata <8, it was illegal, as I recall.)

Comment: @NickCox Thanks Nick. The Update cleared it up. Will be more specific with my questions/examples in the future.

Answer (score 1):

This uses the trick of encoding using the order of another variable to get the sorting right:

```
sysuse auto, clear
keep if foreign==1

sencode make, gen(encoded_make) gsort(-weight)
levelsof encoded_make, local(labels)
tw scatter price encoded_make, mlabel(weight) c(1) xlabel(`labels', value angle(45)) sort(weight)
```

You will need to install `sencode` from SSC.

Comment: In effect `sencode` does here what `labmask` does. Both are user-written.

Comment: This code is better when there are the same labels in the dataset.